# Line offset issue with Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, line

I'm using Geoserver 2.6.2 and QGIS 2.10 to check my WMTS display. According to the documentation, I have tried 2 different ways to draw a line offset for a line-type layer, but none is working correctly.

If I test my SLD within Geoserver GUI, I get an error message on the `PerpendicularOffset` line. In QGIS, my layer is displaying but the offset is not taken into account.

**Test 1:**

```
   <LineSymbolizer>
     <Stroke>
       <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
     </Stroke>
       <PerpendicularOffset>3</PerpendicularOffset>
   </LineSymbolizer>
```

**Test 2:**

```
   <LineSymbolizer>
     <Stroke>
       <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
     </Stroke>
       <VendorOption name="PerpendicularOffset">3</VendorOption>
   </LineSymbolizer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at the [latest documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/linesymbolizer.html#syntax) then that is the correct syntax but you are using an old GeoServer so need to consult the [older manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/linesymbolizer.html) which makes no mention of the parameter. If you'd like to use this feature you will need to upgrade your GeoServer version to 2.9+.

Comment: You are right... I did not care about documentation version! Thanks again...